# extends class in flutter with "<p1,p2>"

Tags: flutter

I"m new to flutter and I"m trying to understand the following class extends:

`class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {LoginBloc() : super(LoginState());`

What does it mean
**extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState>**

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter, the `extends` keyword is used to inherit from other classes. In this particular case your `LoginBloc` class is inheriting from the `Bloc` class.

The `Bloc` class takes two dynamic types when it is defined; an Event class and a State class. Flutter/Dart convention is to type everything that you can. The `Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState>` is defining that `LoginEvent` is the blocs Event class and `LoginState` is the blocs State class.

You will use these two classes to control the state changes in your code. LoginEvents emitted from the front end will trigger functions in the LoginBloc which will then emit different LoginStates which you can listen for on the front end.